# how to configure vite.js to output a file main.js without a hash

Tags: vite

I'm trying to configure vite.js to output a file without a hash in the filename so i can reuse it always in the same way in django template.

My vite config file is like this :

```
import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

export default defineConfig(({ command, mode }) => {
  const envMode = mode === 'development' ? 'development' : 'production';
  const env = loadEnv(envMode, process.cwd(), mode === 'development' ? '.env' : '.env.prod');

  return {
    root: '.',
    plugins: [react()],
    build: {
      outDir: 'static',
          rollupOptions: {
            output: {
        // Customize the asset filenames
        assetFileNames: 'assets/[name][hash:0].[ext]'
      }
      },
    },
    define: {
      __APP_ENV__: JSON.stringify(env.APP_ENV),
    },
  }
})
```

I have tried with assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[ext]' and assetFileNames: 'assets/[name].[.js]' but it doesnt work.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve this by setting build.rollupOptions.entryFileNames to `main.js` in my vite config file.

```
build: {

  ...others here,

  rollupOptions: {
     output:{
       entryFileNames: `main.js`
     }
  }
}
```